How to refresh local Swift Package after adding files in Xcode 16?
Since upgrading to Xcode 16, I've noticed that when I add new files to my local Swift packages, the "Update Package" option is no longer available when I right-click on my local package.
In previous versions of Xcode, I used this feature to make Xcode recognize newly added files without any issues.
Now, with Xcode 16, the only way I've found to get Xcode to recognize new files is to remove and re-add the entire package, which is obviously not ideal.
I've tried cleaning the build folder and rebuilding the project, but it doesn't seem to help.
Is there a new workflow or method in Xcode 16 to refresh or update local Swift packages without needing to remove and re-add them every time?
Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!
What I’ve tried so far:
Cleaning and rebuilding the project
Looking for any options under "File > Packages" menu

Environment:
Xcode 16
Local Swift Package

Thanks in advance!

I am currently solving this by using File -> Packages -> Reset Package Caches, but this is a workaround that I don't particularly like because, in previous versions, the update was instantaneous.
